# What's wrong with this Apache rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And requests keep causing a 500.

Comment: What does your `error_log` say?

Comment: What does it say in the error log?

Comment: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Comment: If you go straight to /index.php?id=<id>, does it work ok?

Comment: Nope. Same issue with `/` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entering rewrite loop. Change it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

or like this (should have the same effect behind):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well, thanks, is seems to work. Can you provide a little bit of explanation?

Comment: Sure. After Apache rewrites, for example, `/help` to `/index.php?id=help` it goes to next rewrite iteration. At next iteration it will attempt to rewrite `/index.php` to `/index.php?id=index.php` and will go for next iteration once again. To stop it you have add some condition which will prevent rule from been used.

Comment: Oh, and what about `[L]`? Doesn't it stop the rewrite process?

Comment: The rule I have provided will #1: only rewrite if file is not index.php already or #2: only rewrite if requested resource does not exist (not a file). #2 is better is preferred in general (but since I do not know how many other rules you may have, I have provided mora than 1 approach to the problem).

Comment: `[L]` tells Apache to stop rewriting/matching other rules if this rule matches (but it will go to next iteration anyway as long as rewrite has happened) -- that is the way how it works. See these links: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html